# Intent filter for handling a shared file with a custom extension?

Tags: android, android-intent

My question has been asked a multitude of times before on SO. None of the answers that I found have worked for me. In the `AndroidManifest` I have this filter defined:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

    <!-- for media sharing -->
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
    <data android:mimeType="video/*" />

    <!-- !!! DISABLE this for BoardDrive Lite !!! -->
    <!-- for host imports -->
    <data android:scheme="file" />
    <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.bdhosts" />
    <data android:host="*"/>

    <!-- all other files (disabled for now)-->
    <!--<data android:mimeType="*/*" />-->
</intent-filter>
```

I want BoardDrive to handle shared files for video, audio, pics, and files with a custom extension `.bdhosts`.

When I try to share a file with that extension from ES File Explorer, BoardDrive does not appear in the list.

The full file path is: `/sdcard/BoardDrive/hosts_import.bdhosts`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: can you add this as well in manifest and try : android:exported="true"

Comment: I tried putting this attribute on the `activity` tag (`android:exported=true`) and nothing changed. I should mention that before adding the bit for host imports, I was able to share pics/video/audio.